# Android Studio: How to run tests in Firebase with Orchestrator enabled?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

Is there a way to run instrumentation tests in Firebase Test Lab from Android Studio **with** Android Test Orchestrator enabled?

In my `build.gradle`  I have all of the required statements:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.2'
}
```

When I run tests on my own physical device, Orchestrator is working.

I was able to create a Run/Debug Configuration in Android Studio to run tests in Firebase Test Lab and they run successfully, but with no Orchestrator. Is there an option to enable Orchestrator in Android Studio so that it would also work in Firebase runs?

Comment: The documentation suggests that it works if you run from the Firebase console. Have you tried that?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/firebase-console#new_instrumentation_tests_with_orchestrator

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, I know about that and also about gcloud CLI with `--use-orchestrator` flag, which I tried successfully. But I'm curious about running it from Android Studio. I find it strange that seems like there is no such opportunity.

Comment: You can always file a feature request.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I still have the same problem,how can I resolve this?

Comment: @Mike76 For now I don't know if this feature was implemented. I didn't file a feature request, but maybe this is the way for you.

Comment: any news on this question?

Comment: use-orchestrator: true do not work for us. It restarts the previous instance of the app, making tests flaky. Any ideas, why?